# Angular2 parent -> child -> parent binding

Tags: angular

I've seen the following piece of code at work - http://plnkr.co/edit/5z4VEQ?p=preview

```
<app-component2 [(value)]="value"></app-component2>
```

You can see that we pass a value to a child component and pass it back to the parent when it changes (onChange will only trigger after you focus out of the input box).

Now this code works even though the "valueChange" event emitter isn't subscribed to anywhere. It will only works if the child component has an event emitter and only if said event emitter is called valueChange.

There's obviously some magic going behind the scenes with Angular automagically connecting value and valueChange but I can't find this in the docs / not sure if this is really a supported feature?

Comment: It is all here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html :)

Comment: Could you link to the specific section? It's a rather long document but I did look through it and couldn't find an example

Comment: For input (parent-to-child): https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child for output (child-to-parent): https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#child-to-parent

Comment: Yeah I've read about input output but they use an explicit binding in code for the output where as we seem to be able to use a template binding on the value (input not output) and it magically knows to make the connection to the event emitter (if the name is valueChange - where value is the name of my variable)

Comment: Okay if it is data binding you were looking for (as per answer below,) I suggest you change the title of question a bit, since this has nothing to do with parent-child-parent communication ;)

Answer (score 2):

The behavior you are observing is `Two way data binding`, you may read more about it here at [Template Synatx Guide.](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax)

[image]

Its also mentioned in the [Cheat sheet](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cheatsheet.html)

[image]

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Yup the titleChange binding is what I've missed. This is not mentioned in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html (component communication page) and is a little too magical for my taste (the event emitter has to be named titleChange).

But you get the points :D

Comment: Well, My experience with Angular started with Two way data binding and that was one of the core feature Angular brought for me. So it comes natural to many people how the Two way binding works, I guess that is why it might not be documented, but it should had been, Cheers!!

Comment: I'm all for two data binding, but requiring you to create a specially named output for it to work feels a little odd. I've seen it done in Ember (I think) which is part of the reason I'm not using Ember :D